# Coverlet msbuild /p:Exclude not able to exclude third party dlls

Tags: msbuild, code-coverage, coverlet

/p:Exclude does not seem to work for me - No matter what I try

I want to exclude following third party libraries

```
| DocoptNet | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| HtmlAgilityPack | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Metrics.InfluxDB | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2 | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Microsoft.Practices.Unity | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Replicon.Cryptography.SCrypt | 0% | 0% | 0% |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

using msbuild integration with coverlet.msbuild

```
dotnet test path.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[DocoptNet]*" -e:CoverletOutputFormat="cobertura,json,opencover,lcov" -e:CoverletOutput="TestResults" -e:CollectCoverage="true"
```

ie. I tried following combinations to exclude single dll but does not seem to work.

```
/p:Exclude=\"[DocoptNet]*\"
/p:Exclude="[DocoptNet]*"
/p:Exclude="DocoptNet.dll"
/p:Exclude=\"DocoptNet.dll\"
/p:Exclude=\"[Microsoft.Practices.*]*\"
/p:Exclude="[Microsoft.Practices.*]*"
```

Can someone please help with how to exclude these dlls?
Along with that I also need to exclude multiple third party dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--exclude "[DocoptNet]*"`